# Set based solution to generate batch number based on proximity and type of record in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which has the transactions. Each transaction is represented by a row. The row has a field TranCode indicating the type of transaction and also the date of transaction is also recorded. Following is the table, and corresponding data.

```
create table t
(
    id int identity(1,1),
    TranDate datetime,
    TranCode int,
    BatchNo int
)
GO

insert into t (TranDate, TranCode) 
VALUES(GETDATE(), 1),
(DATEADD(MINUTE, 1, GETDATE()), 1),
(DATEADD(MINUTE, 2, GETDATE()), 1),
(DATEADD(MINUTE, 3, GETDATE()), 1),
(DATEADD(MINUTE, 4, GETDATE()), 2),
(DATEADD(MINUTE, 5, GETDATE()), 2),
(DATEADD(MINUTE, 6, GETDATE()), 2),
(DATEADD(MINUTE, 7, GETDATE()), 2),
(DATEADD(MINUTE, 8, GETDATE()), 2),
(DATEADD(MINUTE, 9, GETDATE()), 1),
(DATEADD(MINUTE, 10, GETDATE()), 1),
(DATEADD(MINUTE, 11, GETDATE()), 1),
(DATEADD(MINUTE, 12, GETDATE()), 2),
(DATEADD(MINUTE, 13, GETDATE()), 2),
(DATEADD(MINUTE, 14, GETDATE()), 1),
(DATEADD(MINUTE, 15, GETDATE()), 1),
(DATEADD(MINUTE, 16, GETDATE()), 1),
(DATEADD(MINUTE, 17, GETDATE()), 2),
(DATEADD(MINUTE, 18, GETDATE()), 2),
(DATEADD(MINUTE, 19, GETDATE()), 1),
(DATEADD(MINUTE, 20, GETDATE()), 1),
(DATEADD(MINUTE, 21, GETDATE()), 1),
(DATEADD(MINUTE, 21, GETDATE()), 1)
```

After the above code, the table contains the following data, well values in the tranDate field will be different for you, but that is fine.

```
id          TranDate                TranCode    BatchNo
----------- ----------------------- ----------- -----------
1           2015-02-12 20:40:47.547 1           NULL
2           2015-02-12 20:41:47.547 1           NULL
3           2015-02-12 20:42:47.547 1           NULL
4           2015-02-12 20:43:47.547 1           NULL
5           2015-02-12 20:44:47.547 2           NULL
6           2015-02-12 20:45:47.547 2           NULL
7           2015-02-12 20:46:47.547 2           NULL
8           2015-02-12 20:47:47.547 2           NULL
9           2015-02-12 20:48:47.547 2           NULL
10          2015-02-12 20:49:47.547 1           NULL
11          2015-02-12 20:50:47.547 1           NULL
12          2015-02-12 20:51:47.547 1           NULL
13          2015-02-12 20:52:47.547 2           NULL
14          2015-02-12 20:53:47.547 2           NULL
15          2015-02-12 20:54:47.547 1           NULL
16          2015-02-12 20:55:47.547 1           NULL
17          2015-02-12 20:56:47.547 1           NULL
18          2015-02-12 20:57:47.547 2           NULL
19          2015-02-12 20:58:47.547 2           NULL
20          2015-02-12 20:59:47.547 1           NULL
21          2015-02-12 21:00:47.547 1           NULL
22          2015-02-12 21:01:47.547 1           NULL
23          2015-02-12 21:01:47.547 1           NULL
```

I want a set based solution and not a cursor or row based solution to update the batch number for the rows. For example, the first 4 records should get a batchNo of 1 as they have TranCode as 1, and the next 5 (having tranCode of 2 and are closer to each other in time) should have batchNo as 2, and the next 4 should have 3 and so on. Following is the expected output.

```
id          TranDate                TranCode    BatchNo
----------- ----------------------- ----------- -----------
1           2015-02-12 20:43:59.123 1           1
2           2015-02-12 20:44:59.123 1           1
3           2015-02-12 20:45:59.123 1           1
4           2015-02-12 20:46:59.123 1           1
5           2015-02-12 20:47:59.123 2           2
6           2015-02-12 20:48:59.123 2           2
7           2015-02-12 20:49:59.123 2           2
8           2015-02-12 20:50:59.123 2           2
9           2015-02-12 20:51:59.123 2           2
10          2015-02-12 20:52:59.123 1           3
11          2015-02-12 20:53:59.123 1           3
12          2015-02-12 20:54:59.123 1           3
13          2015-02-12 20:55:59.123 2           4
14          2015-02-12 20:56:59.123 2           4
15          2015-02-12 20:57:59.123 1           5
16          2015-02-12 20:58:59.123 1           5
17          2015-02-12 20:59:59.123 1           5
18          2015-02-12 21:00:59.123 2           6
19          2015-02-12 21:01:59.123 2           6
20          2015-02-12 21:02:59.123 1           7
21          2015-02-12 21:03:59.123 1           7
22          2015-02-12 21:04:59.123 1           7
23          2015-02-12 21:04:59.123 1           7
```

I have tried very hard with row_number, rank and dense_rank and none of them came for my rescue. I am looking for set based solution as I want really good performance.

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you working with? I feel like some of the newer windowing functions might be able to help, although I haven't figured out how yet.

Comment: how do yo define _"closer to each other in time"_? Or are you just splitting when `TranCode` changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using `Recursive CTE`. I also used the `lead` function to check the next row and determine if you transcode changed.

Query:

```
WITH A
AS (
    SELECT id
        ,trancode
        ,trandate
        ,lead(trancode) OVER (ORDER BY id,trancode) leadcode
    FROM #t
    )
    ,cte
AS (
    SELECT id
        ,trandate
        ,trancode
        ,lead(trancode) OVER (ORDER BY id,trancode) leadcode
        ,1 batchnum
        ,1 nextbatchnum
        ,id + 1 nxtId
    FROM #t
    WHERE id = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT A.id
        ,A.trandate
        ,A.trancode
        ,A.leadcode
        ,nextbatchnum
        ,CASE 
            WHEN A.trancode <> A.leadcode THEN nextbatchnum + 1 ELSE nextbatchnum END nextbatchnum
        ,A.id + 1 nxtid
    FROM A
    INNER JOIN CTE B ON A.id = B.nxtId
    )
SELECT id
    ,trandate
    ,trancode
    ,batchnum
FROM CTE
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 100)
```

Result:

```
id  trandate    trancode    batchnum
1   2015-02-12 10:19:06.717 1   1
2   2015-02-12 10:20:06.717 1   1
3   2015-02-12 10:21:06.717 1   1
4   2015-02-12 10:22:06.717 1   1
5   2015-02-12 10:23:06.717 2   2
6   2015-02-12 10:24:06.717 2   2
7   2015-02-12 10:25:06.717 2   2
8   2015-02-12 10:26:06.717 2   2
9   2015-02-12 10:27:06.717 2   2
10  2015-02-12 10:28:06.717 1   3
11  2015-02-12 10:29:06.717 1   3
12  2015-02-12 10:30:06.717 1   3
13  2015-02-12 10:31:06.717 2   4
14  2015-02-12 10:32:06.717 2   4
15  2015-02-12 10:33:06.717 1   5
16  2015-02-12 10:34:06.717 1   5
17  2015-02-12 10:35:06.717 1   5
18  2015-02-12 10:36:06.717 2   6
19  2015-02-12 10:37:06.717 2   6
20  2015-02-12 10:38:06.717 1   7
21  2015-02-12 10:39:06.717 1   7
22  2015-02-12 10:40:06.717 1   7
23  2015-02-12 10:40:06.717 1   7
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. I will apply it to my problem and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I have tried this solution and it was taking more than 2 minutes for 6K+ records. I took the idea of using lead and applied it differently to my solution so that it takes lesser time.

As others pointed out, a set based solution is really not that elegant and my solution is a mix of while loop with a set based solution

Answer (score 0):

I think that ultimately the operation you wish to perform on the data is not relational, so a nice set based solution doesn't exist. What you are trying to do relies on the order, and on the row sequentially before/after it, and so needs to use a cursor *somewhere*.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get your desired output using a recursive CTE, although it's not optimised, but thought it might be useful to post what I've done to give you something to work with.

The issue I have with this is the `GROUP BY` and `MAX` I'm using on the result set to get the correct values. I'm sure it can be done in a better way.

```
;WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   ID ,
                        TranDate ,
                        TranCode ,
                        1 AS BatchNumber
               FROM     t
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   t.ID ,
                        t.TranDate ,
                        t.TranCode ,
                        CASE WHEN t.TranCode != cte.TranCode
                             THEN cte.BatchNumber + 1
                             ELSE cte.BatchNumber
                        END AS BatchNumber
               FROM     t
                        INNER JOIN cte ON t.id = cte.Id + 1
             )
    SELECT  id ,
            trandate ,
            trancode ,
            MAX(cte.BatchNumber) AS BatchNumber
    FROM    cte
    GROUP BY id ,
            tranDate ,
            trancode
```